# Convex functions on real vector spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

So I'm trying to solve the following problem,

Suppose that $f$ is a non-zero convex real-valued function on a real vector space $V$ with $f(0) = 0$

Show that there is a linear functional $g$ on $V$ such that $g(x) \leq f(x)$ $\forall x \in V$

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know something about supporting hyperplanes? If you do then the exercise is easy: just take an hyperplane supporting the epigraph of $f$ at $(0, 0)$.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything about the theory of 'supporting hyperplanes'. Are you able to introduce this theory to me in a basic language of functional analysis?

Comment: Have a look for the "subdifferential".

Answer (score 1):

The statement of the problem should remind you of the [Hahn-Banach theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem). Of course, the given functional $f$ does not necessarily have the homogeneity that the theorem requires. Let's build it it by letting 
$$F(x)=\inf_{t\ge 0} \frac{f(tx)}{t}$$
You should check that the infimum is finite (using the convexity of $f$), and that $F$ satisfies the subadditivity assumption. Then apply the Hahn-Banach theorem. (The subspace on which $g$ is defined initially can be as small as $\{0\}$.)